# Use of protobuf in a C++ project spanning 3 repositories

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have three repositories, (re)using a set of protobuf files:

```
repo1
 + hello.proto
 + goodbye.proto

repo2
 + hello.proto
 + goodbye.proto

repo3
 + hello.proto
 + goodbye.proto
```

The `.proto` definitions are only evolved in repo1. How should I reuse those definitions? I have trouble finding resources on the correct (or suggested) way and seems like my options are:

1. Distribute the generated (`protoc` compiled) C++ code as a package (say a vcpkg package)
2. Distribute the `proto` files themselves as a package or make a repo out of them and add it as a subrepo to my project

I'm leaning towards option 1, but don't know whether `protoc` is guaranteed to generate the same code on Linux and Windows - will there be any unwanted side-effects. Reusing the proto files seems more safe, but it's more work and maintenance to incorporate them into the build systems of the other repos.

Comment: The generated C++ code is cross-platform and it does not matter where you generate it.

Comment: @Botje partially, you must have same library version and same set of features

Comment: Make one repo that only contains the proto file and produces generate files (either cc files or precompiled static libraries from those cc files). And import those results into your other repos. In a way not all that dissimilar to how you already use 3rd party libraries

Comment: You can still keep the proto file in the sdk of your new component so that other (future) clients in other languages can still build clients too

Answer (score 1):

The protoc utility is guaranteed to generates code appropriate only for toolchain and libprotobuf version it was build with. Porting from Windows to Linux  with same bit order generally works if version oflanguage and library are compatible. Generated code is keyed to the version of runtime. If you ran protoc with v.3.12 library, you will be unable to use it with v.3.13. If you compiled one with former version, it cannot use the latter shared library. It is the wire format what is portable, the compilation units use is limited.

Common practice is to use a folder with "public" .proto files as a sub-repository (a sub-module).

Another option is to create a library with libprotobuf.a (or its analog on non-linux systems) statically linked, which makes whole program portable without having a libprotobuf dependency.

Some real use-cases, e.g. certain aerial telemetry protocols back that up with reverse-engineered description of messages, either in binary or in structured format. That's only the case if there is a need to support languages not supported by protoc or for very small-scale controllers.

PS. protoc supports several languages, are you planning to do same?

Comment: In this specific case, I only want to reuse the C++ generated code in the other repos. Yes, `repo1` generates Python as well, but the artifacts are consumed as wheel packages wherever needed. The `repo2` and `repo3` codebases use a big part of the C++ code, hence my question. If I understood correctly, you disagree with some of the comments: generating files with `protoC` + Linux-gcc, will have different results to generating with `protoC` + Windows-MSVC ?

Comment: @LorahAttkins generated code is attached to version of library. Interal ABI of libprotobuf isn't portable. If you build with *same* version  on both systems, you are likely safe, albeit I've run into issuies when there was difference in supported language features. Then you have to redistribute it, unless you link statically. Actually, for static linking in MSVC you need debug AND release builds done with **matching** compilations flags as your program or you may have issues or even linking failure.